# Is it posslible / How to set default model field option like max_lenght for ex. for specific field project wide

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using django-money which provides me with MoneyField which I use a lot in my project.
But MoneyField expects to always have max_digits option. How can I set a default for this kind of field to avoid typing it all the time and worse maintaining it later?

Answer (score 3):

Make your own class that derive from `MoneyField`. Then use that class instead of `MoneyField`.

For example:

```
DEFAULT_MAX_DIGITS = 10

class MyMoneyField(MoneyField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_digits'] = kwargs.pop('max_digits', DEFAULT_MAX_DIGITS)
        super(MyMoneyField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: looking at all the things that django simplifies I really hoped that it will by just the one line on setting.py but it is what it is, maybe in some future version... anyway thanks!